# Using a parameter within two different Python files

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use a parameter between two different python files. I have the `locators.py`, where I have defined the locator:

**locators.py**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    class MainPageLocatars(object):
      ELEMENT = (By.XPATH, "//label[text() = '%s']"%(i))
```

In this file, I have the `i` defined.

**main.py**

```
import locators 
from locators import *
from locators import MainPageLocatars

def __selectCheckbox(self, checkbox, locater):
        if checkbox == "All":
            if self.driver.find_element_by_id(locater).is_selected() == False:
                self.execute_script_click(MainPageLocatars.CHECKBOX)
        else:
           if self.driver.find_element_by_id(locater).is_selected() == False:
                self.execute_script_click(MainPageLocatars.CHECKBOX)
                self.execute_script_click(MainPageLocatars.CHECKBOX)
           elif self.driver.find_element_by_id(locater).is_selected() == True:
                self.execute_script_click(MainPageLocatars.CHECKBOX)
           for i in checkbox:
                # only this element is not defined in locators.py
                self.execute_script_click(*MainPageLocatars.ELEMENT)
```

When I run this code, I get an error says `i` not defined. I am importing the locators but not sure why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have the value you to be inside a class. You can just have a file like this:

**MainPageLocatars.py**

```
param1 = "locator1"
param2 = "locator2"
. . .
```

And then in your `main.py`:

```
from MainPageLocatars import *

print param1
```

Comment: The problem I have here is that in the main.py I am using variable i in the loop. Then in the locatars.py I am using that "i" and when I run the test it says i not defined

Comment: @user7242550 Did you try setting up the `locators.py` file as I showed it?

Comment: Yes but it is not working because in my case param1 is not a just a simple text. It is a defined locater in my main.py

Comment: It is like param1 = locator1 instead of param1 = "locator 1"

Comment: Possible to provide example for my code ? I do not seem to understand I apologize.